# Nginx SSL Chrome ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: nginx

I am currently working on a website. I use the Nginx web server as a basis. To secure the whole thing, I also configured SSL. This works quite well in Firefox. But when I call up my website with the Chrome browser I get the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

I followed various instructions and disabled HTTP2 in the Nginx configuration. Since Chrome probably doesn't support HTTP2.

That led to success for a moment. After that I didn't change the configuration and a few hours later I get the same error again.

I also updated Chrome. But it does not work. Firefox and Edge don't show me this error. I tried to use the two different ssl_ciphers. But the problem does not go away.

Here are my SLL settings for include on VHost:

```
# Specify the TLS versions
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# Ciphersuites recommendation from the chiper.li
# Some device will not support
ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384";

# Mozilla Ciphersuits Recommendation
# Use this for all devices supports
#ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';

# Use the DHPARAM key and ECDH curve >= 256bit
#ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:prime256v1:secp384r1:
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam_domain_de.pem;

server_tokens off;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

# Enable HTTP Strict-Transport-Security
# If you have a subdomain of your site,
# be carefull to use the 'includeSubdomains' options
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

# Enable OSCP Stapling for Nginx web server
# If you're using the SSL from Letsencrypt,
# use the 'chain.pem' certificate
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.de/chain.pem;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;

# XSS Protection for Nginx web server
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
```

Here is my Nginx VHost Configuration without HTTP2:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.de www.domain.de;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        root   /var/www/domain.de;
        index index.html index.php index.htm;

        server_name domain.de www.domain.de;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.de.log warn;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.de/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.de/privkey.pem;

        include snippets/ssl_domain.de.conf;
        include snippets/certbot_domain.de.conf;
        include snippets/locations_domain.conf;  
}
```